# Performance comparison of ZipArchive and PharData PHP class

Tags: php, performance, zip, tar, php-ziparchive

Since TAR is just an archive, I thought I can get faster performance if I use PharData (creating tar file) in place of ZipArchive (creating zip file) class.

The following is my TAR creation step.

```
$zip = new PharData("file.tar");

foreach ($valid_files as $file) 

{

$zip->addFile($file, str_replace('/', '', strrchr($file, '/')));

}


The Zip creation step is given below

$zip = new ZipArchive();

if($zip->open("file.zip",$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {

return "zip open failed. Exiting<br/>";

}

foreach($valid_files as $file) {

$zip->addFile($file,str_replace('/', '', strrchr($file, '/')));

}

$zip->close();
```

Does anyone know why TAR creation was slower than zip creation? Input to both of them are JPEG files.

Comment: Hipothesis: Ram can be faster that HDD access. If compression is effective and fast, the overall process of storing a deflated file can be faster than the plain file.

Answer (score 1):

Find out how much time does it it take to execute each code. Hence we can determine which is faster.

```
$time_start = microtime(true); 

//Zip/Tar creation code

$time_end = microtime(true);

// calculate execution time in seconds
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start);

//execution time of the script
echo '<b>Total Execution Time:</b> '.$execution_time.' Seconds';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already found out that ZipArchive performs better than PharData. But that is the problem. Tar-ing is supposed to be faster than zip-ing.